# String still null after reading file to it

Tags: android, string, bufferedreader

I've a string object s. I write to it using a `bufferedReader.readline()`. I've logged out the contents of s and in logcat i can see them, so i know it's not null. I later use s and call `String.split` on it, but i'm getting a NPE, why, when it's already populated so not null?

thanks.

```
String cachePath = getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(cachePath + "/dbcache/" + "cacheTextFile.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String s = null;
        try {
            while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "s = " + s);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {

            fr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 



        HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Log.e(TAG, "about to call on s"+s.length());
        String[] arr = s.split(",");

        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i=i+2){
            String key = arr[i].toString();
            hash.put(key, "-1");
            Log.e(TAG, "hash key = " + hash.get(key));
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `while`, you are always overriding the `s` string..so when you reach the end it will be `null`

```
 while((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
    Log.e(TAG, "s = " + s);
 }
```

Do this instead..

```
 StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
 String currentLine = null;
  while((currentLine = br.readLine()) != null)
        stringBuilder.append(currentLine + "\n");
```

Comment: sorry i don't follow. why is s still null?

Comment: while((s = br.readLine()) != null) here when you arrive at the end, and execue readLine it will return null, so s will be null, and then you will exit the while loop